# Chyper SharedPreferences GSON objetcs

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences, gson, des

I want to store an encrypted Profile object in `SharedPreferences` using gson.

Here's my code:

```
public void saveProfile(Profile newProfile) {
  try {
    Log.i(C.TAG, newProfile.toString());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    String profileJSONfied = new Gson().toJson(newProfile);
    Log.i(C.TAG, profileJSONfied);

    byte[] cleartext = profileJSONfied.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8);
    Log.i(C.TAG, cleartext.toString());

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    String encrypedProfile = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(cleartext), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.i(C.TAG, encrypedProfile);

    editor.putString(PROFILE, encrypedProfile);
    editor.commit();
    profile = newProfile;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(C.TAG, e.getMessage());
  }
}

public Profile loadProfile() {
  try {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    Log.i(C.TAG, prefs.getString(PROFILE, null));

    // byte[] plainTextProfileBytes = Base64.decode(cipher.doFinal(prefs.getString(PROFILE, null).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8)), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] plainTextProfileBytes = Base64.decode(prefs.getString(PROFILE, null).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.i(C.TAG, new String(plainTextProfileBytes, HTTP.UTF_8));

    profile = new Gson().fromJson(new String(plainTextProfileBytes, HTTP.UTF_8), PROFILE_TYPE);
    Log.i(C.TAG, profile.toString());

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(C.TAG, e.getMessage());
  }
  return profile;
}
```

Here's an output example (ordered by Log's order):

**saveProfile:**
Profile@4146a1d8
{"email":"aaa","firstName":"aaa","lastName":"aaa","postal":"aaa", etc etc...}
[B@414819b0
+nLS7XhRoIFPBeC11/h6mMz6hFfc8js03QJ8VwVZH+dPBeC11/h6mJ448CLGPNzz+bU669XpAI8VXchYQJr7mgDwHpeoSrP4BMACydjKpC8Q9atbk9xz6HNqDpNOiqaa75hFM+r9pzm55/E2E2tdjz4s5OzNNppAPzmtS69tZAZLPuYt1kvnJehHa6fDt2o5UCv6VukCwvVgt+UDcCqCKvF22Iv6vdMXWTcm

At this point I think everything went as expected. The problem lies below, decipher operation
**loadProfile:(backward process)** 
+nLS7XhRoIFPBeC11/h6mMz6hFfc8js03QJ8VwVZH+dPBeC11/h6mJ448CLGPNzz+bU669XpAI8VXchYQJr7mgDwHpeoSrP4BMACydjKpC8Q9atbk9xz6HNqDpNOiqaa75hFM+r9pzm55/E2E2tdjz4s5OzNNppAPzmtS69tZAZLPuYt1kvnJehHa6fDt2o5UCv6VukCwvVgt+UDcCqCKvF22Iv6vdMXWTcm
�r��xQ��O���z���W��;4�|WY�O���z��8�"�<���:������]�X@�������J�����ʤ/�[��s�sj�N����E3��9���6k]�>,���6�@?9�K�mdK>�-�K�%�Gk�÷j9P+�V���`��p*�*�v؋��Y7&���-A

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 21`

If I instead of:

```
byte[] plainTextProfileBytes = Base64.decode(prefs.getString(PROFILE,null).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I use:

```
byte[] plainTextProfileBytes = Base64.decode(cipher.doFinal(prefs.getString(PROFILE, null).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8)), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

The error will be:

```
pad block corrupted
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found a solution!
 For starters I've changed a bit of my code. I've created a myPBEkey class with two methods, encrypt and decrypt, both return a Cipher object with the respective "opmode":

Then I've changed my saveProfile and loadProfile methos code to:

```
public void saveProfile(Profile newProfile) {
    try {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            String profileJSONfied = new Gson().toJson(newProfile);             
            byte[] encryptedProfile = pbeKey.encrypt().doFinal(profileJSONfied.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8));       
            byte[] encryptedProfileBase64 = Base64.encode(encryptedProfile, Base64.DEFAULT);            

            editor.putString(PROFILE, new String(encryptedProfileBase64, HTTP.UTF_8));
            editor.commit();
            profile = newProfile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(C.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

```
public Profile loadProfile() {
    if (profile == null) {
        try {                   
            byte[] decodedProfileBase64 = Base64.decode(prefs.getString(PROFILE, null), Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] plainTextProfileBytes = pbeKey.decrypt().doFinal(decodedProfileBase64);

            profile = new Gson().fromJson(new String(plainTextProfileBytes, HTTP.UTF_8), PROFILE_TYPE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(C.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
return profile;
```

I think what solved the problem was separating the encrypt/decrypt from `Base64` encode/decode, so first we encrypt and then encode the encrypted `byte[]` and finally store it. The same goes when decrypting, first we decode the encrypted base64 profile and then decrypt the decoded  `byte[]`.   Voilà!
Thanks for your time, hope it helps you.